# JPA: several relations

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, one-to-many, one-to-one, many-to-one

I have much trouble with JPA and the right annotations and tried a lot of annotations and combinations like @JoinColumn, mappedBy and so on, but still get errors. I use EclipseLink (JPA 2.1).

I have the owner class Store:

```
@Entity
public class Store extends BaseEntity {

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @OneToMany
    private List<Price> listPrices;

    @NotNull
    @OneToMany
    private List<BusinessHours> listBusinessHours;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="store_id")
    private PointCoordinates pointCoordinates;
...
}
```

This is the class PointCoordinates:

```
@Entity
public class PointCoordinates extends BaseEntity {

    @NotNull
    private float long;

    @NotNull
    private float lat;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="pointCoordinates")
    private Store store;
    ...
}
```

And this is one of the "@OneToMany" classes of 'Store':

```
@Entity
public class BusinessHours extends BaseEntity {

    private Boolean holiday;

    @ManyToOne
    private Store store;
    ...
}
```

I thought that it should work, because 'Store' is the owner of 'PointCoordinates' so I have to annotate the attribute `private Store store` with `@OneToOne(mappedBy="pointCoordinates")` and on the other side I have to annotate the attribute `private PointCoordinates pointCoordinates` with `@JoinColumn(name="store_id")` But I still get the same error:

Error message on Glassfish 4.0

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception
>   [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Fehler beim Zuweisen einer
>   Verbindung. Ursache: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Lokale
>   Transaktion enthält bereits 1 Nicht-XA-Ressource: weitere Ressourcen
>   können nicht hinzugefügt werden.  Error Code: 0 Call: INSERT INTO
>   POINTCOORDINATES (ID, LAT, LONG) VALUES (?, ?, ?)     bind => [3
>   parameters bound]

Error message on Glassfish 3.1.2.2 (English)

> Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Fehler beim Zuweisen einer
>   Verbindung. Ursache: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Local
>   transaction already has 1 non-XA Resource: cannot add more resources. 
>   Error Code: 0 Call: INSERT INTO POINTCOORDINATES (ID, LAT, LONG)
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?)  bind => [3 parameters bound] Query:
>   InsertObjectQuery(com.company.entities.output.rest.PointCoordinates@3a6a03ea)

Comment: This looks like if you have problems with your environment. Do you use an application server or a servlet container? If you think that your JPA code is responsible for this exception try commenting out the relation.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your dedication, but I solved the problem, have a look on my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the answer! I got this error because I annotated PointCoordinates with "@NotNull". This is wrong, you should use the attribute "optional".

The reason for the other error I got "Local transaction already has 1 non-XA Resource: cannot add more resources" happened because I had several different transactions with several Persistence Units.